# Re-rendering useEffect from child component

Tags: reactjs

```
const CompleteDriverInfo = () => {
  const [DriverInfo, setDriverInfo] = useState([]);
  useEffect(async () => {
    await setDriverInfo(await GetFetch('driver'));
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <Link to='/adddriver'>
        <button className='btn btn-primary'>Add Driver</button>
      </Link>
      {DriverInfo.map((EachDriver) => (
        <EachDriverInfo EachDriver={EachDriver} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const EachDriverInfo = ({ EachDriver }) => {
  const DeleteDriver = (e) => {
    POST(
      'deletedriver',
      {
        CustomerName: EachDriver.CustomerName,
      },
      e
    );
  };
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Name: {EachDriver.CustomerName}</h1>
      <h1>Phone Number: {EachDriver.PhoneNumber}</h1>
      <h1>Email: {EachDriver.Email}</h1>
      <h1>Address: {EachDriver.Address}</h1>
      <h1>Country: {EachDriver.Country}</h1>
      <button onClick={(e) => DeleteDriver(e)} className='btn btn-primary'>
        Delete Driver
      </button>
    </>
  );
};
```

When I click `Delete Driver` in my child component, it deletes a driver from the database, but the page doesn't re-render until refresh because of useEffect's empty dependencies.

I was thinking of setting a parent state from the child component and putting that in the dependency array but it feels like an anti-pattern

Comment: Why is it an anti-pattern? You should update your state. It is ok to update state of parent from child component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly fine to update parent state from the child component. Just pass a function to the child component, and when child component changes the state, call this function inside the child component so that the parent component can update the app state and the rerender.

Here is a sample [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-shadow-iyeuu):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Posts = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getPosts = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get(
        `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`
      );

      setPosts(response.data);
    };
    getPosts();
  }, []);

  const handleDeletePost = (id) => {
    const updatedPosts = posts.filter((p) => p.id !== id);
    setPosts(updatedPosts);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {posts.map((post) => (
        <PostInfo key={post.id} post={post} deletePost={handleDeletePost} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const PostInfo = ({ post, deletePost }) => {
  const DeletePost = async (id) => {
    await axios.delete(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/{id}`);
    deletePost(id);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Id: {post.id}</h1>
      <h1>Title: {post.title}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => DeletePost(post.id)} className="btn btn-primary">
        Delete Post
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default Posts;
```